# We have $2n+1$ irrational numbers, then exists $n+1$ of them such that every subset of this set with $n+1$ elements has the sum an irrational number.

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, graph-theory

> Show  that  if   we  are given a set $S$ containing $2n+1$  irrational  numbers,  there  exists a subset $T\subset S$ containing $n+1$ elements, such that every   non-empty subset   of  $T$ sums  to an  irrational  number.

I   tried   to  consider an equivalence relation on  real numbers: two  elements  are  equivalent iff   the   difference  of   them  is  irrational. Then $n+1$  equivalence classes each have a representative that is "positive" or "negative" ... but  I  don't  know  hot  to  continue.

Any  idea? Thank  you!

Comment: what do you mean by "every subset of this with $n+1$ elements..",? Are the subsets you are referring to the subsets of the $n$ numbers? In which case, you cannot have a subset of size $n+1$.

Comment: @AnuragA, the text says "exists $n$" but the title says "exists $n+1$."  I suspect the title is correct.

Comment: @BarryCipra That makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Winther, but the OP wants the sum of every *subset* (of, presumably, a set of size $n+1$) to be irrational, so it doesn't help to add an irrational element to a set (of size $n$) whose sum is rational.

Comment: @AnuragA I  edited  the  post. Thank you!

Comment: "Having an irrational difference" is not an equivalence relation because it is not transitive: $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ have an irrational difference, $\sqrt{2}$ and $2$ have an irrational difference, $1$ and $2$ have a rational difference. "Having an irrational difference" is not reflexive either: for any $a$, $a-a\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: One idea is to do a proof by contradiction. If every subset $S$, such that $\mid S \mid = n+1$ there exist $A \subset S$ such that $\sum_A a \in \mathbb{Q}$, then we can find two subset $B$ and $C$ such that : $C = B \cup \{g\}$ and $\sum_B, \sum_C \in \mathbb{Q}$ but this is a contradiction since $g \not\in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Perhaps, it is best to say "every ***nonempty*** subset."  The sum of elements of the empty set is usually defined as $0$, a rational number.

Answer (score 5):

We may solve this through a suitable labelling technique: we associate to each element of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_{2n+1}\}$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$. We start by associating to $a_1$ the vector $(1,0,0,0,\ldots)$, then we process $a_2,a_3,\ldots$ according to the following algorithm:

- If all the subsets of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ which include $a_n$ have irrational sums, we associate to $a_n$ the vector $v_n$ with a $1$ in the $n$-th position, zeroes anywhere else (encoding the idea that *$a_n$ gives something new with respect to the previous additive structure*);
- Otherwise we consider the smallest (according to the lexicographic order) subset of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, including $a_n$, with a rational sum: assuming it is $\{a_{k_1},a_{k_2},\ldots,a_{k_h},a_n\}$, we associate to $a_n$ the vector $-v_{k_1}-v_{k_2}-\ldots-v_{k_h}$ (encoding the idea that "*$a_n$ does not bring something new with respect to the previous additive structure*")

If you manage to prove that the sum of the coordinates of $v_n$ is never zero, you have that at least $n+1$ vectors among $v_1,\ldots,v_{2n+1}$ belong to the same half-space $\sum x_k>0$ or $\sum x_k<0$ and they are associated to a $(n+1)$-subset of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_{2n+1}\}$ with the wanted property.

Comment: I am wondering if this is not similar to Batominovski's proof

Comment: @Thinking: I am wondering too. We actually wrote them almost simultaneously.

Comment: Yes what's nice is that yours doesn't use AC. This problem was very instructive.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can  you   explain  the  last  part? Thank  you!

Comment: I don't think the last paragraph is right. You don't need to prove anything about the sum of coordinates of $v_n$. Instead, let $m$ be the number of basis vectors $v_i$. Choose $w \in \mathbb{Q}^m$ such that it's not orthogonal to any $a_i$. Then one half plane is $\{x | x \cdot w > 0 \}$. You can always find an non-orthogonal $w$, because the set of vectors orthogonal to a given vector is a proper subspace, and any finite union of proper subspaces over an infinite field is not equal to the whole space.

Comment: I forgot to say that you can find a non-orthogonal vector only if the other vectors are non-zero, which is the case in this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the statement is as follows.  My version of the problem is stated a little bit awkwardly because I want to include the cases where the given irrationals are not necessarily distinct.  My proof is based on the Axiom of Choice.

> **Problem.** Given are $2n+1$ irrational numbers $t_0,t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{2n}$.  Prove that there exist $n+1$ of them, say, $$t_{i_0},t_{i_1},t_{i_2},\ldots,t_{i_n}\,,$$ with indices $i_0,i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n$ satisfying $0\leq i_0<i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_n\leq 2n$, such that any sum of the form $$t_{i_{j_0}}+t_{i_{j_1}}+t_{i_{j_2}}+\ldots+t_{i_{j_k}}\,,$$for some $k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and indices $j_0,j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_k$ with $0\leq j_1<j_2<\ldots<j_k\leq n$, is irrational.

Pick a basis $\{1\}\cup\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Well order $\mathcal{B}$ with an order $\triangleleft$.  For each $b\in\{1\}\cup\mathcal{B}$, let $\pi_b:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Q}$ be the projection sending $x=\sum\limits_{a\in\{1\}\cup\mathcal{B}}r_aa$ to $r_b$, where $r_a\in\mathbb{Q}$ for $a\in\{1\}\cup\mathcal{B}$ with finitely many nonzero terms. Then, there exists a lexicographic ordering $\prec$ on the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ as follows.  For $x,y\in\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, we say $x\prec y$ if there exists $b\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $\pi_b(y-x)>0$ and for every $a\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $a\triangleleft b$, $\pi_a(y-x)= 0$.  Show that $\prec$ is a total order on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, and it is compatible with addition, that is, if $x,y,z,w\in\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ satisfy $x\preceq y$ and $z\preceq w$, then
$$x+z\preceq y+w\,.$$

We say that $x\in\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is *pozitiv* if $0\prec x$, and $x$ is *negaziv* if $x\prec 0$.  Since the $2n+1$ numbers are irrational, there images under the quotient map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ are nonvanishing.  Therefore, at least $n+1$ are pozitiv, or at least $n+1$ of them are negaziv.  Then, take $n+1$ pozitiv elements, or $n+1$ negaziv elements to complete the proof.

Comment: "such that any sum of the form"...what? You left out the important bit!

Comment: @TonyK  Forgot two words.

Comment: @Batominovski This is a beautiful proof. (+1) Nevertheless I am sure there is a more elementary proof without using the axiom of choice. As you proof shows the number $n+1$ is there so that we can cut $2n+1$ in two parts of size $<n+1$.

Comment: (+1) Brilliant indeed, but I am wondering: did we just write the same thing, differently worded?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  I'm pozitiv that we wrote the same thing, but your version is very nice.