# Prove among some irrational numbers, there exists some numbers in that set s.t. each pairwise sum is irrational.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

This question is basically a weaker statement of the question found here: [We have $2n+1$ irrational numbers, then exists $n+1$ of them such that every subset of this set with $n+1$ elements has the sum an irrational number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987636/we-have-2n1-irrational-numbers-then-exists-n1-of-them-such-that-every-sub).

> Prove that among $2n + 1$ irrational numbers we can choose $n + 1$ numbers such that the sum of any two chosen numbers is irrational.

However, I am looking for a proof that is both more elementary and that uses graph theory. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875785/graph-theoretic-proof-of-irrational-number/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Let $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_{2n+1}\}$ be the set of irrational numbers. Take $X$ to be the vertex set of a graph $G$ whose edges are the pairs $\{x_k,x_\ell\}$ such that $x_k+x_\ell\in\Bbb Q$; you want to show that $G$ has an independent set of size $n+1$. You can do this by showing (by contradiction) that $G$ has no odd cycle and concluding that $G$ is bipartite.

**Added:** To show that $G$ has no odd cycle, suppose that the vertices $x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_{2k+1}}$ form such a cycle. Then the sums

$$x_{i_1}+x_{i_2},x_{i_2}+x_{i_3},\ldots,x_{i_{2k}}+x_{i_{2k+1}},x_{i_{2k+1}}+x_{i_1}$$

are all rational. Now take the alternating sum of these sums:

$$(x_{i_1}+x_{i_2})-(x_{i_2}+x_{i_3})+(x_{i_3}+x_{i_4})-\ldots-(x_{i_{2k}}+x_{i_{2k+1}})+(x_{i_{2k+1}}+x_{i_1})\;;$$

it must be rational, but it simplifies to ... ?

Comment: the odd cycle part is pretty slick :D